# How to make pairs using nested loop in Lisp

Tags: loops, while-loop, lisp

I am trying to make a pairs function in Lisp. The pairs function gets two inputs then makes a pair with each other and make one list. Here is my code:

```
(defun npair (s1 s2)
  (let ((result '()))
    (cond ((null s1) s2)
          ((null s2) s1)
          (t (loop
               (when (null s1) (return result))
               (while (not (null s2))
                 (setq result (cons (list (car s1) (car s2)) result))
                 (setq s2 (cdr s2)))
               (setq s1 (cdr s1)))))))
```

This function should have returned like `(npair '(a b c) '(1 2))` -> `((a 1) (a 2) (b 1) (b 2) (c 1) (c 2))`

But my result is only `((a 1) (a 2))`.
Please help!

Comment: WHILE is unknown, your code can't run.

Comment: Your `null` case conditions mean that this is not a correct Cartesian product. If either list is empty, the result must be empty: because the combination of every element of a non-empty list with every element of an empty list is empty. Of course, we can define a function however we like; it's just unlikely to be of useful value if it outputs gratuitously *ad hoc* special cases.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to accumulate the value(s) from an inner loop in an outer loop, you're probably better off simply accumulating the values rather than trying to do it by mutating variables:

```
(loop for e1 in p1
   append (loop for e2 in p2
             collect (list e1 e2)))
```

Your formatting is also way off, the custom is to not put terminating parentheses on a new line.

Using the loop construction from above, your entire function would thus be:

```
(defun npair (p1 p2)
   (loop for e1 in p1
      append (loop for e2 in p2
                collect (list e1 e2))))
```

Nice, simple and quite readable.

Answer (score 1):

While the others have shown you better alternatives to achieve the result you want than your implementation, here's the reason why your implementation doesn't work: you change the value of `s2` to `null` while combining the first element of `s1` with the elements of `s2`, and never restore the original value of `s2` before handling the remaining elements of `s1`. (This is one of multiple good reasons why you should loop over the input values without mutating them in the first place.)

Here's a version of your implementation what actually works because it doesn't mutate its inputs:

```
(defun npair (s1 s2)
  (let ((result '()))
    (cond ((null s1) s2)
          ((null s2) s1)
          (t (loop for e1 in s1
                do (loop for e2 in s2
                      do (push (list e1 e2) result)))
             (nreverse result)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

by the looks of it, the result you hope for is called a *cartesian product*.

An implementation that I use in the Scheme programming language goes like this:

```
(define (product . args)                                                             
   (if (null? args)                                                                   
       (list '())                                                                     
       (apply append                                                                  
              (map (lambda (rest)                                                    
                    (map (lambda (first)                                             
                            (cons first rest))                                       
                          (car args)))                                               
                  (apply product (cdr args))))))
```

For example here is the output using Chez Scheme:

```
> (product '(a b c) '(1 2))
 ((a 1) (b 1) (c 1) (a 2) (b 2) (c 2))
```